# Getting keyword suggestions with AdWords API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-api, google-ads-api

When you use the AdWords pannel you see something like this:

[image]

I am trying to get the response as JSON via API. First is it even doable? Does Google allow that?

Second thing is: I am using Node. I found a couple of modules ([node-adwords](https://github.com/ChrisAlvares/node-adwords), [googleads-node-lib](https://github.com/ErikEvenson/googleads-node-lib)), but cannot find any information about the ***keywords*** themselves. It seems these can only be used for getting the details about *campaigns*.

I found [this](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/keywords-performance-report) in the documentation (not exactly what I'm looking for but close), and [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/tree/master/examples/AdWords/CSharp/v201802/Optimization) code example. Unfortunately this is for .NET.

So my question is: How can I use Node to get the keywords suggested by Google?

I will be keep searching and posting new info as I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data you're looking for from the Google AdWords API using the [TargetingIdeasService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201802/TargetingIdeaService.TargetingIdea).

Comment: Any idea if there is a node module for this?